# Is there a way to wait until all the data has been written to a csv file in selenium (nodejs) before exiting the test?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to write some data from a table to csv file. It does work most of the times, but sometimes it only writes few of the data to the file and exists the test. So I was wondering if there is a way to wait until all the data has been written to a file and proceed further or something like that.
Here's my sample code:

```js
async writeRecords(records: T[]): Promise<void> {
        const headerString = !this.append && this.csvStringifier.getHeaderString();
        const recordsString = this.csvStringifier.stringifyRecords(records);
        const writeString = (headerString || '') + recordsString;
        const option = this.getWriteOption();
        await this.write(writeString, option);
        this.append = true;
    }Is there a way to wait until all the data has been written to a csv file in selenium (nodejs) before exiting the test?

WriteToCSV = async (filename, data) => {
        if (!filename) {
            await this.logger.Fail('Must provide a filename in order to save a CSV file');
        }
        const reportPath = await GetReportPath(filename, Strings.CSVExt);
        const writer = createArrayCsvWriter({
            path: reportPath,
        });
        await this.logging.Trace(`dataset=${data}`);
        const formattedData = await this.FormatCSVData(data);
        await this.logging.Trace(`formatted=${formattedData}`);
        await writer.writeRecords(formattedData);
};
```

Comment: don't use async...

Comment: I have to use async because selenium web-driver is async and most of the functions that we use are async, so I have to use async....is there any nodejs module that has that functionality?

Comment: webdriver calls are not really async or you'd need "await" for every action you do.  There is a definite sequence to actions... one thing happens and then the other.  You can actually call this method before the next action just make sure it's not async.

Comment: also consider the webdriver.get method.  This is an actual get call made by the in-between server, and not javascript.  (Your first page is blank so there's no way to insert javascript there... they have to do this instead of setting window.location...)  While javascript is async, these calls all wait on callbacks or you'd have no order to your actions...(which looks to be your problem here... you're in another "thread" running outside of the actions...)  I'm not familiar with Node, but you're going to want to " wait until all the data has been written to a file and proceed further"

Comment: worth noting that Selenium always re-checks the DOM on pageload event.  When the site uses javascript to populate portions of the DOM, this does not fire and an "expectedConditions" wait is needed to access anything that has updated.  It "polls" the DOM for the condition to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but how about using `with open (filename)` or something similar??